# Is there a way to create an app in Android that can immediately copy messages all messages received on WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I would like to create an app that automatically copies messages from WhatsApp and translates them. Is there a way to let an app copy messages from WhatsApp?

Answer (score 1):

While receiving those messages in order to translate them is a pretty noble intent, WhatsApp is an end-to-end encrypted messaging service that values security. Aside from rooting the device to circumvent permissions, I truly hope there is no way for another app to access WhatsApp messages in order to maintain that security. I'm sorry, even if you found a sneaky undocumented way to access them, it'd be rightfully patched as soon as word got out.

If you have a fairly up-to-date phone with the Google Assistant on it then you might be able to use it to translate text on your screen. It's worth pointing out that whoever you use as a translation service might cause a problem around privacy. Whether WhatsApp translates it or Google does, translation always comes with privacy concerns.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to get the text from the notification?

Comment: I didn't think of that. I can already see some stipulations (won't work on devices that are "[Low Ram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isLowRamDevice())" and it won't retroactively get previous messages). I wonder how well the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) can access notifications from [Secure Apps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)? Does WhatsApp use this flag? There's a lot to look into.